# How to extend/get reference to rule-view inplace-editor?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-developer-tools

I'd like to extend the Firefox inspector's rule editor. I did find `editableField` in [inplace-editor.js](http://derplnmiit.appspot.com/github.com/mozilla/releases-mozilla-central/blob/c00ba7e9ccd06cb62f0509930a95022f99a4038a/browser/devtools/shared/inplace-editor.js) which is referenced by [rule-view.js](http://derplnmiit.appspot.com/github.com/mozilla/releases-mozilla-central/blob/c00ba7e9ccd06cb62f0509930a95022f99a4038a/browser/devtools/styleinspector/rule-view.js). In what XUL window can I grab a reference to these objects and extend them?

Considering the popularity of color-picker for Firebug, and other similar addons, I hope this is possible, I wonder if there is a guide somewhere for this?

Answer (score 1):

The rule-view now has a color-picker editor and more specific editors are coming too (cubic-bezier timing-functions, gradients, ...)

If you wish to extend the features of the rule-view further, I don't think extending the inplace-editor is the right way to do it anymore.

You might be interested in the following files:

- *browser/devtools/styleinspector/style-inspector-overlays.js* which manages all types of tooltips and highlighters that are specific to the rule-view. For instance it is where the color-picker tooltip is created and made so that it appears when the user clicks on the little color swatches.
- *toolkit/devtools/output-parser.js* which is responsible for parsing css values that appear in the rule-view and adding the color swatches to them.

It's unfortunate but no guide exist as of today to extend the rule-view (or the inspector in general for that matter).

Comment: There is some documentation on the inspector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) in the Developer API section, may be a bit out of date. Some time ago I made a [color-picker](https://github.com/programmin1/DevTools-Tweaks/commit/73c3147537f2f54c551c5a426e55806bea67a1b0) for older Firefox but it just conflicts with the latest versions, and was removed. In other words, it seems to be a moving target, hopefully should be settling down enough for better documentation soon.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to extend what the inplace editor does (like adding a color picker dropdown menu), I would overwrite the _createInput method:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/devtools/shared/inplace-editor.js#226

Something along these lines:

```
let {InplaceEditor} = require(inplace-editor);
InplaceEditor.prototype._createInputOld = InplaceEditor.prototype._createInputOld;
InplaceEditor.prototype._createInput = function() {
  this._createInputOld();
  // My custom code....
}
```